# What does the colon mean in jquery? Is it like an else statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is a short line of code:

```
data:  {comment: $('#modal_form #note').val(), patient_ids: ids},
```

I'm just trying to figure out in what reference it's being used in between "patient_ids: ids"

Comment: This is an object initializer and has nothing to do with jQuery. This is basic JavaScript syntax. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Using_object_initializers.

Comment: @jrummell: This has nothing to do with JSON.

Comment: The question is about the notation used in Javascript objects. How is it not JSON related?

Comment: @eterps: Because JSON has nothing to do with JavaScript besides that its syntax is based on JavaScript's object initializer syntax. JSON is a textual data representation, like XML.

Comment: @FelixKling is javascript object initialization not the same syntax as JSON?

Comment: @FelixKling So then... it does have something to do with JSON?

Comment: @eterps JSON is a data format

Comment: @eterps javascript literal syntax is a superset of JSON. Javascript literals using the JSON format != JSON literals.

Comment: Thank you gentleman, it's greatly appreciated.

Comment: @jrummell: Only because something *looks* similar, does not mean you can use terminology interchangeably. For example, do you think that `foo = {"bar": 42}` is related to JSON? Not at all, it's Python, assigning a dictionary to the variable `foo`.

Comment: @FelixKling good point. Thanks, I learned something today!

Comment: @jrummell: You're welcome :) Unfortunately many people make the mistake and use the term "JSON" when referring to object literals (which of course is also because "JSON" stands for *JavaScript Object Notation*), but it is simply wrong to do so. Crockford (the creator of JSON) could have named it "PDN" (Python Dictionary Notation) for that matter or "YYAML" (Yet Yet Another Markup Language) (in reference to  YAML) or any other way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code is an object literal

```
{propertyName: "propertyValue"}
```

The left side of the `:` is the object property

The right side of the `:` is the properties value

Comment: I will mark this as resolved in 5 minutes. =]

Answer (score 0):

The `data` object has two variables, `comment` and `patient_ids`

```
data:  {
      comment: $('#modal_form #note').val(),
      patient_ids: ids
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

The line of the code you provided is an example of the JavaScript associative array, which is a collection of the key, value pairs:

```
var data = { key1 : value1, key2 : value2, etc... }
```

You can read the value associated with the key2 as follows:

```
var v2 = data.key2
```

To answer your question, the colon associates the value with the key.

Answer (score 0):

just to round up things, you might said the else beacuse de ternary operator, available in javascript:

```
var textEmpty = text == ""? true : false;
```

that can be written like so:

```
if (text == ""){
    textEmpty = true;
}else{
    textEmpty = false;
}
```

But, as told, that is a completely different use.